# React Native Android Stops Recording When Screen Is Locked

Tags: react-native, audio-recording, android-wake-lock, android-powermanager

I'm using the `react-native-audio-recorder-player` to record audio and I want the app to keep recording when the screen locks.
I've managed to get this working fine on iOS but I'm struggling to do the same on Android. I suspect it's the Android battery optimisation feature that may be the culprit.

Any suggestions would be appreaciated.

I've looked for libraries that can assist in this but I can't seem to find any suitable ones.
Activating wake lock using `@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake` doesn't seem to help.